# How can I allow anonymous users to see a webform, but not submit it?

Tags: webforms

My question title sort of summarizes the issue, I'd like anonymous users to be able to see a webform on a node, but not have access to submit it without logging in. I can't find a straightforward approach for doing this, although I can't imagine that I'm the only one this situation would apply to.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to configure this or a way to code this? I'm asking because a form alter in code can do pretty much anything to a form, and that's well-documented.

Comment: Like making the submit button inaccessible?

Comment: @cilefen if using a form alter hook is the way to do it, I can fiddle around with that, I just thought that this kind of functionality would be more widely used, like showing anonymous users a form to entice them to login/register, so that they can submit it.

Comment: Maybe there is a clicky way to do so. Note I haven't answered the question because I don't know.